# Javascript setattr or setOwnProperty

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a simple array:

```
var arr = ['has_cats', 'has_dogs'];
```

and an object:

```
var obj = new Object();
```

and from the array I want to set object attributes:

```
for( i=0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        if(!arr.hasOwnProperty(arr[i])) {
                // set the object property
        }
}
```

After looping I should be able to call `obj.has_cats` but I can't seem to find a proper way to do it in javascript. In python I would call `setattr(obj,arr[i], value)`. I figured that if objects have a `hasOwnProperty` they should also have a `getOwnProperty` and a `setOwnProperty`.

Any guidance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "I figured that if objects have a `hasOwnProperty` they should also have
>   a `getOwnProperty` and a `setOwnProperty`"

The `hasOwnProperty()` function tells you whether the named property exists as a direct property of the object, as compared to being an inherited property from somewhere in the object's prototype chain. The `in` operator - used like `if (someProperty in someObject) {}` - will tell you whether the object has that property anywhere in the prototype chain.

You don't need a corresponding `setOwnProperty()` function because you can just say:

```
someObject[someProperty] = someValue;
```

I guess the idea of a corresponding `getOwnProperty()` function kind of makes sense if you want a function that only returns a value if the specified property is a direct property, but then there wouldn't be any way to indicate that the specified property wasn't found because null, undefined, false, etc. are all legitimate potential values if the property *is* found. So to achieve that you need to do it as a two-step process using `if (hasOwnProperty())`.

But it doesn't sound like that's what you're trying to do. If I understand you correctly, you just want some way to set a property where the property name is in a variable (in your case, an array element). You don't make it clear what values you want associated to those properties, so I'll just use `true`.

```
var arr = ['has_cats', 'has_dogs'];

var obj = {}; // note {} is generally preferred to new Object();

for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
  // if the property doesn't already exist directly on
  // the object
  if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(arr[i])) {
     // set the object property
     obj[arr[i]] = true;
  }
}

// can access with bracket notation
alert(obj["has_cats"]);

// can access with dot notation
alert(obj.has_cats);
```

Comment: All answers on this page are incorrect, `obj.x = 1` is not a safe way to do `setOwnProperty(obj, 'x', 1)`. Missed case: if a prototype defines property `x` then assignment doesn't create an owned property. To overwrite a prototype property one has to use `defineProperty` on `obj`.

Comment: @jods -  Thanks for the feedback. I find that usually when a property exists in the prototype chain it doesn't make sense to also set an own property of the same name, but anyway the OP's case is a plain object, there aren't inherited properties to worry about, and as per the last paragraph of my answer the question isn't really about inherited properties anyway, it's about how to reference a property name that is in a variable.

Comment: From your own quote, 1st line in answer, the question was "I figured that if objects have a hasOwnProperty they should also have a getOwnProperty and a setOwnProperty". It is an interesting question and it _does_ have practical usages, albeit uncommon ones. I found this question while googling the topic and I thought my comment might help someone else googling for the same.

Comment: @jods - Yes, that quote is part of what the OP said, but in the context of the rest of their question itt isn't really what they were trying to do.  But yes, if somebody really does have a need to set an own property in a situation where the property exists in the prototype chain then your comment will apply. (And in that situation they may also need a way to get the property from the prototype separate to reading the own property.)

Answer (score 2):

You can set the value via:

```
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(arr[i])) {
                obj[arr[i]] = 'value';
        }
}
```

Comment: happens to me all the time ;)

Comment: voted your answer but chose another one for the effort. Thank you guys for responding.

Answer (score 2):

Neither `getOwnProperty` nor `setOwnProperty` would add any value:

The following *always* set the property on the object that evaluated from `x`. Therefore, `setOwnProperty` is nothing more but a property assignment.

```
x[prop] = v
```

Likewise, using a combination of `hasOwnProperty` and property existence it is possible to derive (and supersede) `getOwnProperty`:

```
if (x.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
   // x has prop
   // x[prop] may evaluate to undefined
} else if (prop in x) {
   // prop resolved through [[prototype]] chain
   // x[prop] may evaluate to undefined
} else {
   // property prop not set
   // x[prop] will evaluate to undefined
}
```

Happy coding.

Comment: +1 - you managed with four sentences to say what took four paragraphs in my answer. Nice clear code example too.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overcomplicating this somewhat.  Try this:

```
var arr = ['has_cats', 'has_dogs'];
var obj = new Object();
for( i=0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
    obj[arr[i]] = true;
}
```

You don't need to use `hasOwnProperty` against an array when iterating it by its indices.  Though perhaps you meant to check against `obj` as a guard against overwriting anything that was already set?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property with:

```
obj[arr[i]] = "my value";
```

In javascript property access can be either done by `.name` or `['name']`.